# move-semantics and std::future

Tags: c++, c++11, future, move-semantics

I work myself into the C++11 features and recognized the move-semantic and try to apply it to at least every function that handles container or "bigger" objects. Now I found some tasks that I would like to run in parallel so I would use std::future, but these tasks handle containers (in my situation return a container).
So I have this pseudo code:

```
std::future<container&&> c = std::async([]()->container&&{ /* stuff return a local container object */ });
```

And know I ask myself how is the lifetime controlled of a container rval ref? If I am right and the task is finished before I call c.get() it is stored. Will the stored value still contain a usable object?

Does this ensure it's lifetime?

```
std::future<container> c = std::async([]()->container&&{ /* same stuff -- ^ -- */ });
container cc = std::move(c.get());
```

Comment: does `/* stuff */` create `container` as a local object ?

Comment: `c.get()` already returns a `container &&`, so the `move` in `container cc = std::move(c.get());` does not do anything.

Comment: You probably don't want to return a `container &&` for your lambda.

Comment: @PiotrS. Yes, it does.

Comment: @nwp (It should) Not in the second pseudo code.

Comment: @JoshuaBehrens, the `std::move` still does nothing, because in the second code example `get()` returns an rvalue, so you don't need to use `std::move` to cast it to an rvalue (see my answer)

Comment: @T.C. Why(referable to Jonathan Wakelys answer?)

Comment: @JoshuaBehrens: because it is a dangling reference when it refers to local object, as the object itself is destroyed at the end of lambda's body

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks as though you're doing move semantics wrong.

You should return by value, not by rvalue reference, and let the move constructor ensure that returning by value is efficient.  Otherwise you risk returning a dangling reference to an object that no longer exists. The point of move semantics is to make passing objects by value cheap, rvalue references are just the language feature that enables that, the goal should not be to use rvalue references for their own sake.

In other words, you want to *move* the data from the lambda body, to the lambda's return value, to the future's stored value. That **moves** the data. You don't want to pass around a reference, that doesn't *move* anything (and you could already pass things by reference in C++03 using lvalue references!)

Your lambda should return by value, and the `future` should store by value:

```
std::future<container> c = std::async([]()->container{ /* stuff */ });
```

And you don't need to use `std::move`, unique futures return the stored value as an rvalue, so you can move from it automatically without using `std::move` to cast it to an rvalue:

```
container cc = c.get();   // cc will be move constructed
```

Comment: Thanks for your instant edit. So I do not need to enforce the usage of move? If I got it right, lvalues will result in a copy and rvalues result in move(if possible)? 'dangling reference' that is what I meant when I wrote about the lifetime.

Comment: Yes, lvalues get copied and rvalues can be moved. All `std::move` does is cast something to an rvalue, it's redundant to use it on things that are already rvalues.

Comment: @JoshuaBehrens lvalues get copied, unless the compiler is able to elide that copy. If your lambda returns a local instance of `container`, don't move it in the return statement. IOW, this will allow NRVO `[](){ container c; /* stuff */ return c; }`, while moving will not.